# Need to add element tags along with '+' symbol in Json Output

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xslt

I want to add the element tags in a json output along with the Plus symbol, at the end of word spaces, I had used some XSLT, in that i got the json output with plus symbol, but the element tag is not coming.

My Input xml is:

```
<description>
<p>Here are some things other smokers say that they like about smoking:</p>
<ul>
<li>Smoking is a reward I can give myself when I finish a task.</li>
<p>Write your thoughts here. . .</p>
</description>
```

My XSLT Used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:json="http://json.org/"  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="80"/>

<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" select="concat('((.{1,', $length, '})( |$))')"/>

<xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="' +&#10; '"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:break" as="xs:string">
<xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
<xsl:variable name="result">
<xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
<xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', regex-group(2), '&quot;')"/>
<xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
<xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="description">
"description": <xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space())"/>,
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
<p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
<ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
<li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Json Output as:

```
"description": "Here are some things other smokers say that they like about smoking:Smoking is a" +
"reward I can give myself when I finish a task.Write your" + 
"thoughts here. . .",
```

But my expected output as:

```
"description": "<p>Here are some things other smokers say that they like about smoking:</p><ul><li>Smoking is a" +
"reward I can give myself when I finish a task.</li></ul><p>Write your" + 
"thoughts here. . .</p>",
```

Please help me on this. I want the output with element tags as well as plus symbol. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? If you have Saxon 9 PE or EE (for instance, inside of oXygen) then you can serialize the nodes first and then call the function I posted in an earlier response on the serialization of the nodes. If you have Saxon 9.7 HE then you can simply set `version="3.0"` and you can even serialize in the open source version with `"description": <xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space(serialize(node()))"/>`.

Comment: Presently I'm using Saxon 9 PE processor in oxygen, i tried with SAXON 9.7 HE with version 3.0, Its not changing in output @Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can use the XPath 3.0/3.1 serialize function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize), for instance by using Saxon 9.7 HE (or PE or EE of course) and setting `version="3.0"` in your stylesheet then you can serialize the nodes you have first and then apply the function to break up the string into chunks. I would also suggest to switch to output method `text` as mixing XML or HTML with plain text does not work well with the output method `xml`. So try

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="80"/>

<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" select="concat('((.{1,', $length, '})( |$))')"/>

<xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="' +&#10; '"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:break" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', regex-group(2), '&quot;')"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="description">
    "description": <xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space(serialize(node())))"/>,
</xsl:template>
```

and the output is like

```
                "description": "<p>Here are some things other smokers say that they like about smoking:</p> <ul>" +
 "<li>Smoking is a reward I can give myself when I finish a task.</li> </ul>" +
 "<p>Write your thoughts here. . .</p>",
```

you can change that parameter `length` as needed to adjust where the line break happens.

Comment: Its working, But I'm getting output like this "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><p>Here are some things other smokers" the xml versions and coming along with this. please help on this

Comment: I used the code as posted and then Saxon-HE 9.7.0.14J outputs what I have shown in my response, using `xsl:output method="text"` I don't get any XML declaration. You will need to explain in more detail what you do and which version you use when you get a different output.

Comment: I'm using Saxon-PE 9.6.0.7, i used version as 3.0 and xsl:output method="text" also, But I'm getting output as " "description": "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><p>Here are some things other smokers say" + " Please help on this

Comment: Well, if you need to use Saxon PE with that particular version then start reading its documentation http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/about/index.html to try to find out what you need to change. http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/functions/fn/serialize.html seems to suggest you can provide some second param with output options.

Comment: I tried @Martin, But its not coming, I asked this issue as new question. Please answer in that. Thanks